# After logging out ,the user is able to go back using back button how to resolve this issue

Tags: angular, authentication, routes, logout, guard

route.ts

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    canActivate: [AuthguardGuard],
    component: MyNavComponent
  },

  { 
  path: '**', 
  redirectTo: 'login', 
  pathMatch: 'full' 
  }

];
```

Authguard.guard.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { UserService } from './user.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthguardGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private user: UserService) { }
  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    return this.user.getUserLoggedIn();
  }
}
```

User.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {
  private isUserLoggedIn;
  private username;

  constructor() {
    this.isUserLoggedIn = false;
  }

  setUserLoggedIn() {
    this.isUserLoggedIn = true;
  }

  getUserLoggedIn() {
    return this.isUserLoggedIn;
  }
}
```

Login.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { UserService } from '../user.service';
import { FormControl, Validators } from "@angular/forms";


@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  flag = true;
  mobileFormControl = new FormControl("", [
    Validators.required,

  ]);

  constructor(private router: Router, private user: UserService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  loginUser(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e);
    var username = e.target.elements[0].value;
    var password = e.target.elements[1].value;

    if (username == 'admin' && password == 'admin') {
      this.user.setUserLoggedIn();
      this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
      this.flag = true;
    }
    else {
      this.flag = false;
      this.router.navigate(['login']);
    }
  }

}
```

Logout.ts

```
logout() {
    var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to Logout!");
    if (r == true) {
      this.router.navigate(['']);
    }
  }
```

After clicking on logout i still able to move to dashboard component by using browsers back button,how to resolve this please help me out.
I does not want the user to move to dashboard component without logging it again.
means once logout ,the user should need to login again to enter dashboard component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to accomplish it in simpler ways, then just create a global variable ,something like `LoggedInStatus` and when the user is logged in, set this global variable as `true`.
Now, in all the other pages , in ngOnInit() keep the code like

```
ngOnInit(){
    if(!this.global.LoggedInStatus){
        this.router.navigate(['../login']) 
      }
```

and while the user calls the logout(), then just reassign the `LoggedInStatus` to `false`.

This will restrict the users from navigating into any page , without actually login in.

Now, if you want it to be more secure, then when you are calling your login API, pass a sessionID or token and store it in global scope. In each page check the SessionID to validate, orelse redirect to login page.

Comment: I will implemet this

Answer (score 1):

You can handle this by creating token/sessions.

1. Every time you login, create a token and use it throughout the application.
2. If you navigate to different pages you will maintain the same token.
3. At any point in time, from any page of your application if you press logout button then  destroy the token.

By doing this I can restrict user going back to previous page after log out.

Answer (score 0):

Use it.

```
this._router.navigate(["/signIn"],{replaceUrl: true});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.